# Unisoc T606 smartphone

Tags: android, mobile, phone, smartphone

Oukitel WP23Pro specs: https://www.gsmarena.com/oukitel_wp23pro-12650.php

This has to be the hardest platform I come across for unlocking bootloader and rooting.

1. There is no downloadable firmware, so I don't know how to extract the boot.img and vbmeta-sign.img from the phone, so I can't unlock the bootloader and install TWRP etc.
2. Looking at the WP23Pro's little brother WP23, which has a downloadable pac images you can flash, extracting boot and vbmeta-sign.img from. You will find Manufacturer used its own OEM key. So I assume it's the same in WP23Pro version two.
3. I have tried every known: fastboot oem unlock, fastboot flashing unlock commands for unlocking the bootloader, inkluderad oem get_identifier_token and using the key in : ./signidentifier_unlockbootloader.sh XXXXXX rsa4096_vbmeta.pem signature.bin, and trying to flash the key:

fastboot flashing unlock signature.bin /
fastboot flashing unlock_bootloader signature.bin /
fastboot flashing --force unlock signature.bin

Nothing I do seems to work.
So how can I root existing firmware or flash a prerooted GSI?.